# How to disable top-level statements in .ipynb notepads from Polyglot extension in vs code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, polyglot, toplevel-statement

How to disable top-level statements in .ipynb notepads from Polyglot extension in vs code?

Only found how to disable them when creating a new console application - dotnet new console --use-program-main and it works! But I need exactly in notepads from Polyglot extension. Is there any way to change the configuration of .JSON files?